# How to uninstall Ruby which was build from source?

Tags: 16.04, uninstall, compiling, make, ruby

I wanted to install ruby version 2.2.3, so I downloaded the source and installed from there as per instructed here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-from-source

But however now I want to remove this installation. I tried `sudo apt-get remove ruby` and it does not work.

Comment: When installed with make, apt and dpkg aren't used so it does not record the install. Does the source support uninstall? `sudo make uninstall`

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo make uninstall` from the source folder worked.